# Как пишется слово "неединична"?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Как пишется слово *неединична*? Например, ситуация неединична.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нужно следовать общему правилу написания *не* с прилагательными. 
Если утверждается неединичность — слитно, если отрицается единичность — раздельно.

> [Вопрос № 235355](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=235355++++)
>   Подскажите, как написать слово с «не» в следующем предложении: И это не единичный случай.
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Если мыслится противопоставление, то пишется раздельно.

Но надо сказать, что слитное написание встречается крайне редко. В Нацкорпусе есть 227 вхождений с раздельным написанием и только два со слитным.

- Раздельное написание

> И это был **не единичный** случай сочувственных отношений русского, украинского населения. [Александр Черкасов, Александр Лавут. Крымские татары. XX-XXI века // «Знание - сила», 2009]
>
> Во всяком случае, феномен Саввы Морозова ― **не единичное** российское явление. [Галина Шергова. …Об известных всем (2002-2004)]

- Слитное написание

> Это, вообще-то, **неединичный** случай, художник здесь лишь подхватывает идею у жизни и реализует ее в формах самой жизни. [Илья Утехин. Любимые вещи (2004) // «Неприкосновенный запас», 2004.01.15]
>
> Нечего и говорить, что передать эти эпизоды, даже **неединичные**, нет никакой возможности. [Н. Цуриков. Дети эмиграции (1925)]

То, что в вопросе стоит краткое прилагательное, сути дела не меняет.

> Не с краткими прилагательными пиши, как с полными: дорога нелегка (трудна, тяжела) = дорога нелёгкая (трудная, тяжёлая).  [(§111. НЕ с краткими прилагательными](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/rules/111))

Answer (score 0):

**Ситуация не единична.**

Слово ***неединичный*** сложно найти в толковом словаре, так как значение у него неясное.

ЕДИНИЧНЫЙ,  1. **Крайне редкий,** исключительный, не характерный. Е. пример. Е-ые экземпляры книги. Случай этот далеко не е. 2. **Отдельный, обособленный**. В единичном явлении художник видит черты типического.

А ***неединичный*** ― это какой? Вот кто-то говорит, что "частый", но вряд ли это правильно. Это ― не крайне редкий, не исключительный, не отдельный, так что можно считать, что  **практически** нет у этого слова утвердительного значения, а поэтому верна раздельная форма письма.

Можно, конечно, найти отдельные примеры, можно говорить об общих правилах, искать утверждение или отрицание, но смысла в этом нет. Доказывать, что вы правильно выбрали слитное написание придется долго и без гарантированного успеха.

Кстати, здесь можно применить правило: **НЕ пишется раздельное, если относится к словосочетанию:** единичный случай - не единичный случай (= такие случаи бывают).

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=78#pp78

§ 146. Отрицание ***НЕ*** пишется раздельно в следующих случаях.

7. **С любыми сочетаниями слов:**
   а) с сочетаниями, состоящими из знаменательных слов (в этих случаях **отрицание относится не к тому слову, которое следует за не, а к целому словосочетанию**), напр.: не кандидат наук, не гражданин России, не научный сотрудник, не специалист в области филологии, **не прямо пропорциональный;**  http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=78#pp78

Comment: Неединичный — может быть, = ординарный, обыкновенный?

Comment: До такого значения слово не дотягивает.  это именно "не очень редко, не в единичных случаях".